# Android: How can I add Google map to a ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-viewpager

I want to make an app that has on the main screen a ViewPager with a map and a profile section. Therefore, for position = 0 in the ViewPager, there is the map and for position = 1, there is the profile.

For each one of those two "sections" on the main screen, I have two activities: the map.xml with the MapActivity.java and the profile.xml with Profile.java. Both of those are inflated in the EnumFrag java class, depending on the position ( you see there an if ).

I have two issues:

1. The first one is that when I try to slide left or right, the map moves, not the ViewPager to the next slide. I tried to put a shape on the edge, but it is not working like the slide gesture is passing through the shape. Any help here, please?
2. The second is related to the first one, the MapActivity.java class is not even running because onCreate is not running (I put a Toast there so display something and nothing happened). Any help, please? (I create the map class object).

map.xml contains a simple fragment with an id of map.

MapActivity.java:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Location me;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hey din onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        getLastLocation();
    }

    private void getLastLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hey...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    me = location;
                    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deschide-ti locatia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        MapStyleOptions mapStyleOptions= MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this,R.raw.map_style);
        googleMap.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);

        LatLng point = new LatLng(me.getLatitude(),me.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Me");

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,16));

        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLastLocation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Profile.java

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        EditText username = findViewById(R.id.usernameProfile);
        username.setText(MainScreen.getUsername());

    }
}
```

EnumFragment.java

```
public class EnumFragments extends PagerAdapter {


    private Context context;

    public EnumFragments(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view;
        MapActivity mapActivity = new MapActivity();

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile,null);
                break;
            default:
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map,null);
                break;

        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)container;
        viewPager.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)container;
        View view = (View) object;
        viewPager.removeView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

MainScreen.java

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String username;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private EnumFragments enumFragments;
    private static int userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        userID = extras.getInt("userID");
        username = extras.getString("username");

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.mainSlider);
        EnumFragments enumFragments = new EnumFragments(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(enumFragments);
    }

    public static int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add the MapActivity into the MainScreen Activity. You even don't use the MapActivity in your PagerAdapter class. I would make an other attribute in the constructor of your PagerAdapter, after this :

```
private MapActivity current;


public EnumFragments(MapActivity map_activity)
{
this.current = map_activity;
}
```

then I would put a getter method in the map_activity, wich returns a view, where you can see the current GoogleMap or other features.

> Your problem is that you don't use the new MapActivity...

I hope that may helps you